# Bad result using compute shader

Tags: c++, vulkan

I made 2 examples of rendering (here I only render traingles with a single texture).

The first uses forward rendering : I simply draw triangles directly to the swapchain with a simple fragment shader:

`outColor = vec4(texture(texAlbedo, fragTexCoord).rgba);`

The second uses deferred shading : a first pass draw the scene with the texture and a second pass copy the result pixels to another texture. The second pass only uses a compute shader.

```
imageStore(resultImage, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(albedo.bgr, 1.0));
```

I think both results should be the same but the second get rendering problems.

The result of the first example :
[image]

The result of the second example:
[image]

I don't understand this problem. Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: I'm revealing my ignorance about graphics here, but what's wrong with the second image?

Comment: In the second image texture are ugly, there are waves and the colors doesn't appear as smooth as the first image

Comment: @ArthurMonteiro Is this perhaps due to anisotropic texture filtering?  it looks like the images used in both have different filter settings.   it looks like some moire pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses.
The problem was that in the second example, I was creating image views without mipmap levels.